# Retrieve data from a linked table and display it in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have two Models:

M1:

```
namespace wb01.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class M1
    {
        public M1()
        {
            this.M2 = new HashSet<M2>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int N° { get; set; }
        public string Commentaires { get; set; }
        public int Id_qualité { get; set; }

        public virtual Qualité Qualité { get; set; } //*(Qualité est autre table dans ma BDD)


        public virtual ICollection<M2> M2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a second Model M2:

```
namespace wb01.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class M2
    {
        public int Id_M2 { get; set; }
        public string N_wg { get; set; }
        public double Poids { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual M1 M1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a Controller:

```
namespace wb01.Controllers
{
    using static wb01.Models.M2;

    public class M1Controller : Controller
    {
        private M1Entities db = new M1Entities();

        // GET: M1
        public ActionResult Index()
        { 
            var m1 = db.M1.Include(r => r.Qualité);
            return View(m1.ToList()); 
        }
    }
}
```

I want in my View show the `m1.ToList` with a column contain the Poids of every Id in M1 (means for a `m1_ID` in M1 its Poids= `sum(poids mi_ID in M2)`. Please if someone can help me ?

Comment: Salut, i m afraid you will not get any answer as your sample code is really clear. You have 2 tables M1 and M2 ? Do you have an ID to join them ?

Comment: Yes 2 table M1 and M2, and the primary Key of M1 (Id) is the foreignkey of the Table M2.

Comment: So you can maybe join them and send the result in your view, i will give you an example bellow

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you can try to join your 2 tables:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var query = db.M1    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
        .Join(db.M2, // the source table of the inner join
        t1 => t1.id,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
        t2 => t2.id,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
        (t1, t2) => new { t1 = t1, t2 = t2 }) // selection
        .Where(M1AndM2 => M1AndM2.t1.id == 1);    // where statement

    return View(m1.ToList());
}
```

Comment: I had an error  :( :   "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1 ...« System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[wb01.Models."; I started my View Index with :@model IEnumerable<wb01.Models.

Answer (score 0):

You can project on the columns you need like so

```
var m1 = db.M1.Include(r => r.M2).Include(r => r.Qualité).Select(r => new {
    Poids = r.M2.Sum(x => x.Poids),
    Col1 = r.Col1,
    Col2 = r.Col2,
    Col3 = r.Col3,
    Col4 = r.Col4
});
return View(m1.ToList());
```

Comment: Thank you :) , I tried with your code but I had an error when I tried the Index view: "System.InvalidOperationException: Échec du cast en type valeur 'System.Double', car la valeur matérialisée est Null"

Comment: @lot
are you sure you don't have null poids values in M2
if there is null poids values then you need to filter on non-null `Poids = r.M2.Where(x => x.Poids != null).Sum(x => x.Poids),`